# Continue with setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

To fix things really quick I have to do below logic

```
function ajax(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#something').click(function(){
           //how to continue here? 
        });
    },300);

//api function here
}
```

is there anything call continue in javascript? what I want is wait for the click to happen then only proceed.

Comment: make an example fiddle because it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: continue what, why? It's not clear what your goal is here

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use a flag here:

```
function ajax(allowed){

    if(!allowed){ return false; }

   //api function here
}
```

now call this:

```
$('#something').click(function(){
    //how to continue here? 
    ajax(false);
});
```

---

This can also be used if you want your user to confirm the action to proceed:

```
function ajax(){
    if(confirm('Do you want to continue?')){ // prompts user to allow/disallow
      //api function here
    }
}
$('#something').click(function(){
    //how to continue here? 
    ajax();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

function ajax(){

```
$('#something').click(function(){
   //you received button click event & your magic goes here & may b call your api whatever
});

setTimeout(function(){
    //you cause button click event 
    $('#something').click();
},300);
```

}